# Cordova on Ubuntu 14.10 using netbeans

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, netbeans

I've installed nodejs, npm and cordova under Ubuntu 14.10.  They appear to be in the path:

```
peter@peredur:~$ which node
/usr/sbin/node
peter@peredur:~$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
peter@peredur:~$ which cordova
/usr/local/bin/cordova
```

However, trying to prove the installation by asking for the version of these items give me nothing in the case of nodejs and cordova:

```
peter@peredur:~$ node -v
peter@peredur:~$ npm -v
1.4.21
peter@peredur:~$ cordova -v
peter@peredur:~$
```

If I try to create a cordova project in Netbeans 8, Netbeans simply insists that Cordova is not installed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.10 uses nodejs command insted node

I change the file /usr/local/bin/cordova to use nodejs insted node.

Edit the first line in file /usr/local/bin/cordova

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

And execute again cordova -v

Now your netbeans should work.

I still researching about this. So it's a temporary solution.